# Magento2.3.0 Specific Category associated products not appearing in frontend

Tags: frontend, category-products, magento2.3.0

I am using Magento2.3.0 and my issue is on production mode in front-end side one category inside product not showing on but in admin side all settings are proper and assign product it in this category.

I apply all command including re-indexing  but not showing  in this category inside product.

If any one idea please share it

Comment: Please verify with this table - catalog_category_product, category -product are exist or not. If exists than apply re-index again with remove cache.

Comment: Try to search that assigned product, is it showing in search result?

Comment: Try to search that assigned product, is it showing in search result? yes is it showing it and check it frontend side